# Jquery generate extra code in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

**My code**

```
var google_ad_client = this.title;          
google_ad_client = google_ad_client+"';";  
google_ad_client = "<script type='text/javascript>google_ad_client =\"" +google_ad_client+"</"+"script>";

jQuery('#addSpace').html(google_ad_client);
```

**Output:**

```
<script type="text/javascript>google_ad_client =&quot;ca-pub-1702577941194110" ;<="" script=""></script>
```

Why generate this extra?

```
<="" script="">
```

Wow can I solve this. Any one can please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script like this

```
google_ad_client = "<script type='text/javascript'>google_ad_client =\'" +google_ad_client+"'</"+"script>";
```

Comment: Where is this `type='text` end quote?

Comment: Ok now check again i had changed your code in your way